# HAML multi-select dropbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Been wrestling with HAML a bit this morning. I want my customers to be able to shift-click multiple options in a dropdown. Here is what I have now - a normal dropbox:

```
.form-group
  %label.col-md-4.control-label
    ="#{field_name}:"
  .col-md-8
    = select_tag "filters[#{field}]", options_for_select([["opt1", "1"], ["opt2", "2"], ["opt3", "3"]], selected: current_select_filter_value(field)), class: 'form-control', title: local_assigns[:tooltip].nil? ? "" : tooltip, include_blank: include_blank
```

I have been googling about, etc. to see if there is any easy flag or roundabout way to allow people to simply shift-click. I fear maybe I will need to use a new element entirely - but it would be great if could be achieved via a dropbox. Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `multiple` attribue to the `select` element in your HTML. With [Rails’ `select_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) you can do this by passing `multiple: true` as an option. For example:

```
= select_tag "field_name", options_for_select(...), multiple: true
```

This generates HTML like this:

```html
<select name="field_name[]" id="field_name" multiple="multiple"><option value="1">opt1</option>
<option value="2">opt2</option>
<option value="3">opt3</option></select>
```

and will allow the user to select multiple values.